# Subfolder/Subdirectory and clean URL's

Tags: .htaccess, subdirectory, clean-urls

after doing tons of tests and looking a lot into stackoverflow, I can't figure out how to achieve this.

I have a website served in a subfolder (`www.domain.com/subfolder/`). I have the .htaccess located in that subfolder (`www.domain.com/subfolder/.htaccess`) and I have 3 htmls (`index.html, example1.html, example2.html`)

I want when you access to `www.domain.com/subfolder/example2.html` it opens `www.domain.com/subfolder/example2/` with clean urls and with css, js and image paths working.

I don't know how to set this subfolder as root and continue working clean url's.

This is mi actual .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

I've tried several thing but seems nothing works.

Thanks in advance.
Diego

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in `/subfolder/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder/

# To externally redirect /subfolder/file.html to /subfolder/file/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=302,L]

## To internally redirect /subfolder/file/ to /subfolder/file.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

For `css,js,image` etc make sure to use absolute paths in your HTML or else you can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Comment: Anubhawa ,I am curious to knw, why do we need to match the slash  /+ 1 or more times in THE_REQUEST?

Comment: Hi Anubhava, Have tryed it and doesn't work. When i acces to ``www.domain.com/subfolder/``it look for css, images and js in ``www.domain.com``and when I try to access to ``www.domain.com/subfolder/example2.html``it goes to ``www.domain.com/example2/`` instead of going to ``www.domain.com/subfolder/example2/``

Comment: @Starkeen: some one can theoretically enter `http://domain.com////subfolder/file.html` as URL as well

Comment: @anubhava you're right that works. The issue now is with css, images and js. And if I'm on ``localhost/subfolder/example2/ `` and I click the link to ´´example1.html´´ it goes to ``localhost/subfolder/example2/example1/``

Comment: The correct path is in ``localhost/subfolder/css`` and ``localhost/subfolder/js``

Comment: @anubhava ¿There's no option to do this without using the base?, and if I'm on localhost/subfolder/example2/ and I click the link to ´´example1.html´´ it goes to localhost/subfolder/example2/example1/

Comment: Thanks @anubhava but I have my css like this ``<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css" />`` and still doesn't work

Comment: As you wrote earlier that `The correct path is in localhost/subfolder/css` NOT `localhost//css` that's why `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css" />` will give you 404

Comment: @anubhava Last doubt, you can't set the subdirectory as root to avoid this?

Comment: If you have access to Apache server yes then you sure can

Comment: I have access. How can I do this?

Comment: That can't be answered from comments. I suggest creating a new question so that you get better help.